# The View Scroll when the keyboard is showing

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android, I have a RelativeLayout named A.  It has a view named B in the top of A.  It has a view named C in the bottom of A.

Code I have so far:

```
RelativeLayout A = new RelativeLayout(context);
View B = new View(context);
LayoutParams paramsB = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 40);

paramsB.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
View C = new View(context);

LayoutParams paramsC = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 40);
paramsC.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

A.addView(B,paramsB);
A.addView(C,paramsC);
```

How do I adjust the RelativeLayout size when the keyboard shows?

Comment: so you want the view can be scrolled when the keyboard is showing?

Comment: yes,do you know which method in API?

Comment: can you show me the xml code of your view?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve that:

First you can define the following attribute in  of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

Second you can add scrollview as your parent view of your whole view.

Comment: The first way can't solved.It will resize the layout,I want to the B and C position not be scrolled. The second way ,I don't want to use scollview because some extra reason.

Comment: yes, I have tried ,The whole window will be scrolled,It is not what I want

Comment: hmm maybe I misunderstand your question, can you please re-explain your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set layout parameters of 'A' relative layout to WRAP_CONTENT so that when keyboard comes from bottom then it will adjust the height with relative layout.I doubt about the rules you added to 'B' and 'C' relative layout because you have added Align_parent_bottom and Align_parent_top to true.